# How to add floating action button and center and add animated sub menu in floating action button

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

1. Here is two image on left side is OUTPUT from this package and bottom navigation bar
2. On Right side is my expected Output

[image: Output Result] [image: expected image]

Here is full Source Code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
```

> > > Main Code

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  HomeCubit homeCubit = HomeCubit();
  int currentTab = 0;
  bool _isShowDial = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Tewxt")
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: _getFloatingActionButton(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 100,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () => setState(() => currentTab = 0),
                    child: const Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [Icon(Icons.home), Text("Home")],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () => setState(() => currentTab = 1),
                    child: const Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [Icon(Icons.group), Text("Groups")],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5),
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () => setState(() => currentTab = 2),
                    child: const Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [Icon(Icons.person), Text("Profile")],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () => setState(() => currentTab = 3),
                    child: const Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [Icon(Icons.person), Text("Perfil")],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> Here is the Floating Action Widget Code

```
  Widget _getFloatingActionButton() {
    return SpeedDialMenuButton(
      isShowSpeedDial: _isShowDial,
      updateSpeedDialStatus: (isShow) => _isShowDial = isShow,
      isMainFABMini: false,
      mainFABPosX: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 30,
      isEnableAnimation: true,
      isSpeedDialFABsMini: true,
      paddingBtwSpeedDialButton: 100.0,
      mainMenuFloatingActionButton: MainMenuFloatingActionButton(
        mini: false,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
        closeMenuChild: const Icon(Icons.close),
        closeMenuForegroundColor: Colors.white,
        closeMenuBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonWidgetChildren: <FloatingActionButton>[
        FloatingActionButton(
          mini: true,
          onPressed: () {
            _isShowDial = false;
            setState(() {});
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          mini: true,
          onPressed: () {
            _isShowDial = false;
            setState(() {});
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          mini: true,
          onPressed: () {
            _isShowDial = false;
            setState(() {});
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          mini: true,
          onPressed: () {
            _isShowDial = !_isShowDial;
            setState(() {});
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_down),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          mini: true,
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

***i need right side image output and to implement this i use ([this flutter arc package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_arc_speed_dial/example)) can any one help for this ?***